# Laravel 5.3 Authentication with additional condition

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

Something is changed in Laravel 5.3. In documentation there is this controller where we can add our additional conditions:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

But this controller: AuthController doesn't exist anymore.....
There is only LoginController

Should i create that AuthController or what?

So the question is how to add one more condition for user to login

```
'active' => 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LoginController` in 5.3 for that. One way to do what you want is to override `sendLoginResponse()` method and add something like this in the beginning of it:

```
if (!auth()->user()->active) {
    auth()->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

This will logout the user is he's not active and will redirect him to the root. This will work is `active` is boolean.

Comment: Nice...i made it like this:     public function sendLoginResponse()
    {
        if (!auth()->user()->active) {
            auth()->logout();
            return redirect('login')->with('warning', 'Sie sind noch nicht aktiviert!');
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an [additional condition](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users), like 'active' = 1, in the LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```